# How do i pass dataset or result of Stored Procedure (Managed Instance) to a Web Component in Data Factory?

Tags: azure

I have; Managed Instance / Data Factory / LogicApp.

I can call my Stored Procedure and reference the activity output.

I can call the LogicApp from a Web Component successfully and pass Data Factory dynamic content (such as pipeline name) in the request body.

I cannot pass the dataset from the Stored Procedure into the document body sent to the endpoint.

I have also tried to reference a view in the dataset drop-down of the web component. This data set is not visible to the logic app at design time and i suspect this would not work because apparently LogicApps cannot GET from services behind VPN.

Header; Content-Type = application/json

Body; { "name_a": "@{dynamic_a}" , "name_b": "@{dynamic_b}" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the FOR JSON AUTO clause in my SQL Stored Procedure and wrapped the subquery in a SELECT to alias the column. I referenced this Stored Procedure from Azure Data Factory using a Lookup component to call the Stored Procedure and return the firstrow.columnname. I then placed the JSON returned in the body of the POST request against the Logic App endpoint, hey ho presto voila.